# What does this love quote mean?

Tags: quotes

The following quote:

> A relic cigarette never tastes the same, and that's all I'll preach about rekindling an old flame.

Can be changed into this quote:

> A lighted cigarette never tastes the same, and that's all I'll preach about relighted old flames.

But what does this mean?

Comment: **relic** cigarette or do you mean relit ?

Comment: Your "translation" is wrong. Did you look up "relic" in a dictionary? Did you look up "old flame" as it pertains to love? The simile the makes is quite transparent: a cigarette, when **relit**, never tastes the same as it did before it was originally extinguished. Same thing with loving your ex.

Comment: An [old flame](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/old-flame) means a former romantic or sexual partner.

Comment: yes indeed it was a typo i did mean relit thanyou

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo (relic = **relit**).

Answer (score 2):

As a smoker I suspect that there is a typo in your sentence:

> A reli**T** cigarette never tastes the same, and that's all I'll preach about rekindling an old flame.

Which refers to the fact that when you extinguish a cigarette and light it again afterwards, it doesn't taste the same as when you originally lit it.

The sentence tells you that rekindling an old flame, which means restarting a relationship with someone you broke up with, is like relighting a cigarette. It may seem like a good idea, but you will be disappointed because it never will be the same as it used to be.